# Monitor Change in File That's Not Being Appended To

Tags: shell

I would like to write a shell script that monitors the changes of a file.  That is, another program I've written writes either a 1 or 0 to a file depending on its state.  I would like to create a script that runs indefinitely, and monitors the state of this file.  So far, I've found a close solution online by using tail -f.  However, this command expects the file to be continually appended to.  When I run the following piece of code, I get `tail: test.log: file truncated`.  Also, when I test this program by running `echo 1 > test.log` and `echo 0 > test.log` back and forth on another terminal, it seems that periodically it will completely miss a change in the file.  Probably related to tail expecting to follow the file as it's being appended rather than just changing a single character (thus thinking the file has been truncated, I suppose).

Here's the code I've tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Monitor changes in file

tail -fn0 test.log | \ 
    while read line; do
        if [ $line = 1 ]; then
            echo "TRUE!!!"
        elif [ $line = 0 ]; then
            echo "FALSE!!!"
        fi
done
```

The solution is probably incredibly easy, but I just can't manage to find it.

Comment: tail -F, from what I understand, follows the file with that name, as to avoid the problem of following the same file even after it's been moved/renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture the state of the file in regular intervals, you could do something like this:

```
INTERVAL=2
while sleep 2; do
    val="$(cat "test.log")"
    case "$val" in
        ...
    esac
done
```

Alternately, if you only want to act on the contents of the file whenever the file changes, you need to work with the "modification time". For example,

```
mtime () {
    ls "$1" -l --time-style=+%s | cut -d' ' -f6
}

FILE="test.log"
LAST_TIME=$(mtime "$FILE")
touch "$FILE" #Force first update

while sleep 2; do
    if [[ $(mtime "$FILE") -gt $LAST_TIME ]]; then
        LAST_TIME=$(mtime "$FILE")
        val="$(cat "$FILE")"
        ...
    fi
done
```

If 2 seconds is too big of a delay for your purposes, uses a smaller number. Alternately, use `true` instead of `sleep`, for virtually zero delay.

Comment: Could you explain how to set that up in a script such that I can monitor what the value inside the file is? (ie, 1 or 0), because if I simply replace the `tail -fn0` part with `watch cat`, none of the logic is touched in the snippet of code I posted above.  The script just runs and sits.

Comment: I thought you just wanted to output the value. Do you want to use the value inside your script?

Comment: Yes.  Depending on what the value is, I'd like to perform some functions inside the script.

Comment: Edited. Do you further want to act on $val only when the file changes?

Comment: This is what my script looked like initially.  The only problem is that I would really like to act on a change in a file immediately.  Sleeping introduces some [unwanted] delay.  And I'm afraid that with a small enough sleep, the script will be using too many resources vs what it should be using... if that makes sense.  To your question, essentially yes, this is what I would like to do.

Comment: There, that should do it. I use this for auto-recompiling `tex` files when I'm on a roll with editing.

Comment: And, yes, polling like this does have some overhead, although not too much. If this doesn't work well enough, perhaps you could use `inotify`? It's a linux kernel interface for monitoring file changes, but perhaps it vould involve polling too. Haven't used it, though.

Comment: OTOH, you could change your other program to send a signal to this one whenever it writes to the file. Catching signals in bash is surprisingly easy. And, this would involve no polling, and instant update.

Comment: For that matter, you could use dbus. :-)

Comment: Neither inotify or watch are supported on the system I'm developing on.  And the other program that writes to the file is compiled C.  I'm not familiar with sending signals from C to a shell script (I'm not really familiar with shell scripts at all).  Your solution comes the closest, so I'll mark it.

Comment: @justynnuff You would send the signal to the bash program running the shell. (You can output a shell's PID via the `$$` variable.) But that's a whole nother question's worth. Anyway, good luck.